# How to make a simple ubuntu GUI application from shell script code?

Tags: command-line, ghostscript

[I want this shell script convert to a GUI ubuntu application](http://karve.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/The_Hindu_Delhi.sh)

Any one please help me to make a Ubuntu application. This shell script is used to download Hindu news paper.

Comment: This question deals with GUI scripts: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928019/how-to-make-a-gui-for-bash-scripts][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928019/how-to-make-a-gui-for-bash-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Yad](http://code.google.com/p/yad/) is a fork of Zenity with many
>   improvements.